# Adding a new language (like Java, Javascript etc) in Sonarqube server

Tags: css, xml, web, sonarqube, sonarqube-web

I have 4 XML files(rule set) for languages Java, CSS, XML and WEB (one XML per language)
I was able to import the rules(XML file) for Java language but I dont see other three languages on Sonarqube server. How can I create a new language tab and import their rules? Is there a plugin I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add support for more languages, you need to install dedicated plugins that you will find:

- In the Update Center - read [the documentation about it](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Update+Center)
- Or in the [list of other community plugins](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Other+Plugins) - in which case you have to install them manually by copying the plugin into `<install_folder>/extensions/plugins` folder

Comment: Fabrice, just a question - I was able to add languages using the plugins you mentioned in the links above but when I did that, another profile got added by itself called "SonarQube Way" and it's not even letting me delete that profile. Also 2 other languages "SCSS" and "Less" got added by itself. Any idea why that happened?

Comment: - the plugin you added handle several languages, including SCSS and Less
- SonarQube Way is the default built-int Quality Profile included with the plugin. Feel free to extend this Quality Profile by creating a new one and changing the rules you find appropriate